# How to compare Object and array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops, object

In my application I am trying to compared ids of specification and selectedSpecifications. As of now I hardcoded selectedSpecifications id to 0. I am trying to loop over selectedSpecifications array and then check if id matches.

```
selectedSpecifications  is an array
specification  is an object
```

I need help to achieve this functionality.

```
 let val = this.selectedSpecifications.map(specification => {
        
   if (specification.id == this.selectedSpecifications[0].id) {  ----> How can I remove
 hardcoded value `0` and loop over selectedSpecifications array

        return specification.value ;
}
else{
       
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main point of clarification is the syntax for `map` and `find` is `arr.map(eachElementInArray => doSomethingWithElement)`, but it seems like you're trying to reference the specification as an argument (the other way around). Instead, you want something like this:

```
let val = this.selectedSpecifications.find(selectedSpec => {
   if (selectedSpec.id === specification.id) {
        return selectedSpec.value;
}
```

If there's only 1 or no matching specification, I would use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Otherwise `map()` makes sense if there are multiple matching specifications.

As a final note, I would rather use the [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) (`===`) here just in case the saved id's have different types, which might help you catch a bug.

Comment: It says `Cannot find name 'specification'.ts(2304)`

Comment: Can you please clarify what `specification` is besides an object? What is it supposed to represent? It seems like it wasn't defined earlier in the code.

Comment: That is right, when I passed earlier to map it worked but not in the above case. I need to check